# Find the area of the part of the surface $z=x^2+y^2+2$ that lies above the disc $x^2+y^2 \le 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the area of the part of the surface $z=x^2+y^2+2$ that lies above the disc $x^2+y^2 \le 1$ correct to four decimals by expressing the area in terms of a **single integral**

I would really appreciate any hints on the use of **the single integral only**. I have been able to solve this using a double integral but using just a single integral is a bit difficult.

Comment: surface of revolution....

Comment: Transition to cylindrical coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say, lateral surface area = S between radius 0 and 1.

Equation of the paraboloid, $z = x^2+y^2+2 = r^2+2$

$
\begin{align}
S &= \int_0^12\pi r ds \ ,\text { where ds is the arc length} \\
& = \int_0^12\pi r \sqrt{1+(\frac{dz}{dr})^2}.dr \\
& = \int_0^12\pi r \sqrt{1+4r^2}.dr
\end{align}
$

Say, $t = 1 + 4r^2$
Then $r.dr = \frac{dt}{8}$

$t = 1$ at $r = 0$, $t = 5$ at $r = 1$

Substituting in above integral,

$
\begin{align}
S & = \frac{2\pi}{8}\int_1^5 \sqrt{t} .dt \\
& = \frac{\pi}{6}[t^{3/2}]_1^5 \\
& = \frac{\pi}{6}[5\sqrt5 -1]
\end{align}
$

Comment: I hope it is clear that the arc length ds is $\sqrt{(dr)^2+(dz)^2}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

> Find the area of the part of the surface $z=x^2+y^2+2$ that lies above the disc $x^2+y^2 \le 1$ correct to four decimals by expressing the area in terms of a **single integral**.

The area is $$\int_0^12\pi r \frac{dr}{\cos\theta}=\int_0^12\pi r\sqrt{4r^2+1}dr=\frac{\pi}6\left[(4r^2+1)^\frac32\right]_0^1=\frac{\pi}{6}(5\sqrt5-1)$$ where $\tan\theta=\frac{dz}{dr}=2r$.

I don't think the area can be calculated without *implicit* double integration. Here, $\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi=2\pi$ is implicit.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Appreciate it